# How to let the user select multiple choices while filtering data using django-filter?

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a model:

```
class Radiations(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=models.ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE, default=None)
    date=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    done_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    base_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=None)
    expected_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=None)
    remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, default=None)
    radiations_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Its filter looks like this:

```
class RadiationsFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    patient__name=django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Name')
    from_date=django_filters.DateFilter(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), field_name='date', label='From - Date ', lookup_expr='gte')
    to_date=django_filters.DateFilter(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), field_name='date', label='To - Date ', lookup_expr='lte')
```

Now, I want the user to be able to select multiple patients which are saved in the database, how can I bring them into my filter code? Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new filter field like:

```
patients = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    queryset=Patient.objects.all()
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not give me the option to select multiple names. Even if I select multiple names by pressing cltr, it shows results for only one patient. What's wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there is data for other patients? Have you overridden init, clean or any other method which could manipulate data?